# Back end field is not disabling in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, forms

I am new to magento, here I created the custom module in that Created & Updated field is there. I don't want to show these two fields for this i given disabled=true. but it's displaying.

**my code is**

```
$fieldset->addField('created_dt', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Created Date',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'created_dt',
                'disabled' => true,
                'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ));
```

can tell me where I went wrong or how to resolve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` will only make the form field disabled.
If you want it not visible, instead of type `text` use `hidden`.  So your field should look like this:

```
$fieldset->addField('created_dt', 'hidden',
    array(
        'name' => 'created_dt',
        'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    )
);
```